# Expanding macros to Pascal Code in Inno Setup [Code] section

Tags: macros, inno-setup, preprocessor, pascalscript

I was trying to make a macro to avoid duplicating code and comments.

I tried this:

```
#define GrowOnPage(any Page, any Component) Component.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth; Component.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akTop];
```

However, it can't find the macro. I simply tried calling it like a normal function / procedure:

```
GrowOnPage(configPage, configTextField);
```

Maybe I am completly missunderstanding macros here. But the documentation doesn't have any examples.

The reason I am not making a procedure for this, is that the `Anchors` property isn't available in a common parent class of components such as `TCustomEdit`.

What would be the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To evaluate a preprocessor function, you have to use a preprocessor directive. The most usual way to achieve that is using the [`#emit` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit).

Though note that Inno Setup preprocessor *functions* are not like C *macros*. They are really *functions*. So if you want to use them to produce a part of your script, they have to evaluate to a string. Like this:

```
#define GrowOnPage(str Page, str Component) \
    Component + ".Width := " + Page + ".SurfaceWidth; " + \
    Component + ".Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akTop];"
```

And use it like this:

```
#emit GrowOnPage("configPage", "configTextField")
```